# Metrics for Explanatory Power of Machine Learning Classification Models

Tags: machine-learning, explanatory-models

I am interested in finding metrics that assess the explanatory power of machine learning models involving binary classification. I know that for logistic regression, McFadden pseudo R squared, AIC, and deviance can be used. I understand that with Neural Networks, it is difficult to determine anything about explanatory power. But what are some quantifiable metrics that can evaluate the explanatory power of models such as Random Forest, K-Nearest Neighbors (k-NN), or other models that are typically used primarily for prediction, specifically in the case of binary classification?

Comment: What do you mean by "explanatory power"? Why is low loss insufficient?

Comment: There isn't really a definition of "explanatory power" as far as I know. In general, a way of assessing how well a model expresses the relationship between a set of independent variables and the dependent variable, possibly with a penalty for too many variables. Like something analagous to AIC or McFadden pseudo R squared in logistic regression. What is low loss?

Comment: I recommend that you look into what a loss function is. That will go a long way towards understanding machine learning.